# Gitlab Ldap Authentication Settings

Tags: authentication, ldap, gitlab

### Current Environment:

- **Gitlab Server:** Centos 6.5
- **Active Directory:** Windows Server 2008 R2

Could anyone check these fictitious settings for Ldap authentication in Gitlab 7.1.1?

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['ldap_host'] = 'myserver.dom.com.net'
gitlab_rails['ldap_port'] = 389
gitlab_rails['ldap_uid'] = 'sAMAccountName'
gitlab_rails['ldap_method'] = 'plain' # 'ssl' or 'plain'
gitlab_rails['ldap_bind_dn'] = 'OU=Users,DC=dom,DC=com,DC=net'
gitlab_rails['ldap_password'] = '????'
gitlab_rails['ldap_allow_username_or_email_login'] = true
gitlab_rails['ldap_base'] = 'DC=dom,DC=com,DC=net'
```

Which **ldap_bind_dn** has to be set in order to Gitlab works (user account equivalent)?

Which **ldap_password** has to be set in order to Gitlab works?

I followed suggestions from: @metaDiego and @heinglandreas. Both were in the right path. So I modified my settings in the lines:

### Solution

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_bind_dn'] = 'CN=the_allowed_user_for_access_ldap,OU=Users,DC=dom,DC=com,DC=net'
gitlab_rails['ldap_password'] = 'the_password_of_allowed_user'
```

The **ldap_bind_dn** may vary according to the AD structure and the current level where the allowed user is located.

My company AD doesn't allow anonymous Ldap queries. So adding those parameters were mandatory.

Search help in the domain administrators, for getting those parameters.

Useful article from [gitlabhq](https://github.com/patthoyts/gitlabhq/wiki/Setting-up-ldap-auth) at Github

If `gitlab_rails['ldap_allow_username_or_email_login'] = true`, the login user could be with email format or only domain user.

[image: Gitlab authentication form]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ldap_bind_dn` has to be the DN of a **user** that has read access to the LDAP. As far as I can see you are pointing to a directory structure with `OU=Users,DC=dom,DC=com,DC=net`. You will have to use that users password as ```

So `ldap_bind_dn` should read something like `uid=userid,OU=Users,DC=com,DC=com,DC=net` and `ldap_password` should then be `userid`s password.

On some LDAP-Servers `ldap_bind_dn` can be left empty as they allow *anonymous bind*. In that case the `ldap_password` has to be left empty also.

Does that make sense? Otherwise feel free to comment!

Comment: For everyone who's searching a solution which is working in 2016 try this: http://serverfault.com/questions/707770/gitlab-active-directory-authentication-no-results-and-no-authentication

Comment: As long as you authenticate against AD. That solution will not work on any other LDAP-Backend.

Answer (score 5):

I have a working GitLab LDAP conf, and the `password` field have to match with the `bind_dn` user you choosed.

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_base'] = 'ou=somehting,dc=foo,dc=bar'
gitlab_rails['ldap_bind_dn'] = 'uid=SOMEONE,ou=somehting,dc=foo,dc=bar'
gitlab_rails['ldap_password'] = 'SOMEONE_PASSWORD'
```

- `ldap_base` is where you search for users
- `ldap_bind_dn` is "the user on the external LDAP server permitted to search the LDAP directory within the defined search base."
- `ldap_password` is the password for the `bind_dn` user. So in your case it has to match with the user `OU=Users`'s password.